# UnitTestCoverage - Remove coverage for .netFramework for contracts dll

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, code-coverage, dotcover

I'm using DotCover to calculate my code coverage %. My contract project is compiled into .net Framework code and .net core.. Since my unit tests are in .net code the code coverage for the contract project in .net framework is 0%.

**How do I filter out the .net framework code? Can't find any DotCover filter to do it.**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at `ReSharper | Options | dotCover | Filtering` page, where you can set up some runtime coverage filters or coverage result filters.

Comment: I looked there are there wasn't anything to remove a type of dll. But only by namespace of dll.

Comment: @Rafi Target frameworks filter will be added in one of the nearest dotCover releases: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DCVR-10053